# Count number of sheets in an Excel file using win32com.client

Tags: python, excel, win32com

Using win32com.client, how can I count all the number of sheets in a excel file?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried and explain how it's not working for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it:

```
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
try:
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(file)
except:
    print "Failed to open spreadsheet " + file
    sys.exit(1)
count = wb.Sheets.Count
```